# Java GUI: Change Label in another class

Tags: java, user-interface

Hi so I have this template program and basically what I need to do is:

When the More Bricks button is pressed a new window opens. When that window there is a button in there and when that is pressed the brick variable should be reset and the label should be reset as well in the original window needs to be reset to its original number. How would I go about this?

This is the first class

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Brick {

    private JFrame firstbricks;

    int price = 0;
    int bricks = 20;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Brick window = new Brick();
        window.firstbricks.setVisible(true);
    }

    public Brick() {
        firstbricks = new JFrame();
        firstbricks.setBounds(0, 0, 272, 130);
        firstbricks.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        firstbricks.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblBricks = new JLabel("20 remaining");
        lblBricks.setBounds(20, 54, 128, 23);
        firstbricks.getContentPane().add(lblBricks);

        JButton btnBricks = new JButton("Bricks");
        btnBricks.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                bricks--;

                if (bricks <= 20) {
                    lblBricks.setText(bricks + " remaining");
                    price += 4;
                }
            }
        });
        btnBricks.setBounds(10, 11, 104, 32);
        firstbricks.getContentPane().add(btnBricks);

        JButton btnExtra = new JButton("More Bricks");
        btnExtra.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                MoreBricks info = new MoreBricks();
            }
        });
        btnExtra.setBounds(131, 11, 115, 32);
        firstbricks.getContentPane().add(btnExtra);

    }
}
```

And here is the second window class which I want the labels to be changed from:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class MoreBricks {

    private JFrame MoreBricks;

    public MoreBricks() {
        makeFrame();
    }

    private void makeFrame() {
        MoreBricks = new JFrame();
        MoreBricks.setBounds(100, 100, 156, 114);
        MoreBricks.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        MoreBricks.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        MoreBricks.setVisible(true);

        JButton reset = new JButton("Reset");
        reset.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });
        reset.setBounds(10, 11, 104, 34);
        MoreBricks.getContentPane().add(reset);




    }


}
```

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Some of your variable are correct, others are not. Be consistent!

Comment: Thanks for this irrelevant comment I do know how to do it this program is just a rush job to help see how to fix my ACTUAL problem

Comment: Yes, well we are not interested in rush jobs. We want actual code that you have tested so we can see exactly what you are doing. Proper naming makes it easier for us to read the code because the forum highlights upper case names as classes. Asking a question is about making it easy for us to want to help you, not doing what is the easiest for you. It takes no more effort to follow Java naming conventions when writing code.

Comment: I have tested this code, this is exactly like the program I am using I just do not need to put in the entire program I just need to fix this problem. Again thanks for the ireelevant comment I know how to name variables maybe you should find out how to comment helpfully!!!

Comment: I do know how to comment helpfully which is why I took the time to make the comment. Until you actually try to help somebody by answering a question you don't know what information is important when solving a problem. Again, look at the formatting of the code. Don't be so selfish. You are asking people who freely donate their time to help you solve a problem. The code is easier to read when properly formatted. There is no extra effort on your part to follow standard naming conventions so that the forums formatting feature works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution (but perhaps not the best), is MoreBricks constructor takes a Brick instance in as the constructor:

```
public class MoreBricks {

    private JFrame MoreBricks;
    private Brick _brick;

    public MoreBricks(Brick b) {
        _brick = brick;
        makeFrame();
    }
```

Then your Reset button just does something like the following:

```
    reset.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            MoreBricks.this._bricks.ResetBrickCount();
        }
```

Ideally you have a "model" class in which all the state of your game (e.g. number of bricks) is encapsulated into a single class.  Then whenever the model changes, all the dependent "views" are notified of the change and update themselves to reflect the right values and state on the screen.

Comment: Why do you think it didn't work?  What did you debug yourself to understand why it's not working?

Comment: yes it didnt work why don't you try it because it doesn't!

Comment: Peter, I see you are new to Stack Overflow and probably new to coding too. The way you get better at programming is not by outsourcing your work for the Internet to do for you. But rather, you make an effort to understand how things work, learn to "debug", and be very specific when describing problems for others to advise on.  You can't say, "It don't work" and expect much help if you have not much to show for what you tried or figured out on your own.

Comment: For example, in your case, there seems to be two problems. The first is a design issue with communicating state changes between two windows.  The other is a simpler problem of how to update the text on a button.  I showed you a template for the former problem, but perhaps the other issue is the latter. But you never indicated that, so that's only a guess.  That's what it means to be more specific.